# Html, Css. Restore div background color to original when mouseout (with bg img)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a group of divs that have the same parent which has a background image. I have a mouseover event to change the colour of the div. I would like the div to have its original colour when mouseout happens. The problem is that the div "color" is not supposed to be something like white or red or a specific color. It is that part of the parent bg image that is behind that div. Each div (is like a square) that is on top of the parent's background image. I would like to for those divs to restore the part of the bg image of the parent they are on top of when mouseout happens.

```
div.onmouseover = function() {   
   this.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // Ok
}
div.onmouseout = function () {
   //change div background to that specific part of parent bg image
}
```

Could someone give me some tips / strategies on how do this?

Comment: best is to use class (add &  remove) and you do not have to deal with lots of css rules :)

Comment: why not just use the `:hover` pseudo class? not javascript is needed here at all.

Comment: Yeah it could probably be simplified. However, that is not the problem. The difficulty I am facing is on how to get that div background to parent's (that part) background...

Comment: If you change the background only on hover - when you mouse-out the background will go back to what it was

Comment: @Dekel that worked. Thank you Dekel.

Comment: @Dekel I will. Well this never happened to me before. I am not sure if I am supposed to do what I just did...

Comment: It's ok :) you can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using classes and the ':hover' property, however if you want to set the styling directly you could Set the background transparent using 'transparent' or rgba for mouseout

```
this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"
```

Or

```
this.style.backgroundColor = rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I do not see why you do this, because if you simply make the background-color transparent, it will show the parent div background.

But if you need this kind of tech for some reason, you need to use Canvas object.
The theory should be like this.
When mouseout triggered:

- You calculate div's relative position about the parent div.
- get the width and height of the div, too.
- create & initialize canvas, and draw the part of image into the canvas
- get the dataURL from the canvas, and then set it as mouse-out triggered div's background.

Code snap is following:

```
var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;
var img_loader = null;


function initCanvas() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = 221;
  canvas.heigth = 221;
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  img_loader = document.getElementById('imgloader');

  var bg = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Flower_poster_2.jpg/677px-Flower_poster_2.jpg';
  img_loader.src = bg;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  initCanvas();
  $('.box').hover(function() {   
     $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
     $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
  }, function () {
    // set div background based on wrapper bg
     var pos = $(this).position();
 ctx.drawImage(img_loader,pos.left,pos.top,canvas.width, canvas.height,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
     $(this).css('background-color','transparent' );
     $(this).css('background-image','url(' + canvas.toDataURL() + ')' );

  });


})
```

[Check the code on JSFIddle: Using Canvas to set the background](https://jsfiddle.net/ray986/rLe0zLr0/)

In order to make sure that image is painted on the sub div, I have made parent div no-background, and just use static image url in the code.
So first you will see dark blue board, and when you hove it will become red, and then when mouse out, the sub picture will be painted.

Answer (score 0):

@Dekel answer.

"If you change the background only on hover - when you mouse-out the background will go back to what it was". Worked fine